# What does this symbol from a voltage regulator schematic, looking like a capacitor connected with with diagonal lines, mean?

Tags: schematics, symbol

What does this schematic symbol mean?

[image]

It is taken from the [LM78XX datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/LM7812-461970.pdf) (figure 17, page 22.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_symbol#Capacitors_(historical)), it's an obsolete symbol for a capacitor with polarity indicator.

[image]